# Why I need to cast "((node)s->top)->next = q" on "push" method? Dubs an declaration pointer to struct

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, stack

I'd like to have explanations regard some dubs. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sNode {
    int data;
    struct sNode* next;
} sNode;

typedef sNode* node;

typedef struct {
    node *top;
    node *head;
    int nodes;
} stack;

void push(stack *s);
void printStack(stack *s);


int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    stack s = {NULL, NULL, 0};
    push(&s);
    push(&s);
    push(&s);
    push(&s);
    printStack(&s);
    return 0;
}

void push(stack *s){
    node q = (node)malloc(sizeof(sNode));
    q->data = rand() % 10 + 1;
    q->next = NULL;
    if(s->top){
        ((node)s->top)->next = q;
        s->top = q;
    } else {
        s->top = q;
    }
    if(s->nodes == 0) s->head = q;
    s->nodes++;
}

void pop(stack *s){

}

void printStack(stack *s){
    printf("Number of nodes: %d\n", s->nodes);
    node q = s->head;
    while(q != NULL){
        printf("%d -> ", q->data);
        q = q->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
}
```

Can you explain me why I need to cast (*node) on function push? Why, also, is sufficient declare a pointer to the struct in this way:

```
stack *s;
```

and start working on? 
What's the difference with this:

```
stack s;
stack *ss = &s;
```

Comment: You shouldn't. And you shouldn't have `node *top` or `node *head` either, since `node` already *is* a pointer, and that makes `top` and `head` of the type `struct sNode **` which seems wrong in this case.

Comment: As for `stack *s;`, that defines a pointer to a `stack`, but a pointer must point to something valid. If you don't make it point anywhere, then each dereference (like `s->top`) will lead to *undefined behavior*. In the case of `stack *ss = &s;` you do make the pointer `ss` point somewhere valid.

Comment: In C code like `typedef sNode* node;` just makes your code unreadable. You *really* want to understand at a glance if a variable is or not a pointer. BTW, enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler: with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) can fail, and you should check for its failure

Comment: so if a declare stack s and then to the function I pass &s it will be fine?